# AWS boto3 describe_mount_targets - Must specify exactly one mutually exclusive parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-efs

I'm trying to run `describe_mount_targets()` with no arguments against an EFS client but getting error

`botocore.errorfactory.BadRequest: An error occurred (BadRequest) when calling the DescribeMountTargets operation: Must specify exactly one mutually exclusive parameter.`

It works fine when calling it with a specific `FileSystemId`.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/efs/client/describe_mount_targets.html shows that all arguments are optional.

Google not showing any results for the error message. Either no one ran into this before or I'm doing something really stupid :)

Comment: The docs say that the FileSystemId must be included in your request if an AccessPointId or MountTargetId is not included. So, at least one of those 3 things must be supplied.

Comment: Thank you for pointing my lack of reading skills :)

Comment: Anyway other way to dump all mount targets for every FS without looping throw them one by one and dealing with throttling?

Comment: Note that I'm aware of. I think you need to describe the file systems, then describe the mount points per file system.